# Formatting 2 columns into list of tuples (for NER)

Tags: pandas, formatting, tuples, append

I'm looking to format data held in a df, so that it can be used in an NER model. I'm starting with the data in 2 columns, example below:

```
df['text']           df['annotation']
some text            [('Consequence', 23, 47)]
some other text      [('Consequence', 33, 46), ('Cause', 101, 150)]
```

And need to format it to:

```
TRAIN_DATA = [(some text, {'entities': [(23, 47, 'Consequence')]}), (some other text, {'entities': [(33, 46, 'Consequence'), (101, 150, 'Cause')]})
```

I've been attempting to iterate over each row, for example trying:

```
TRAIN_DATA = []
    
for row in df['annotation']: 
    entities = []
    label, start, end = entity
    entities.append((start, end, label))
    
    # add to dataset
    TRAIN_DATA.append((df['text'], {'entities': entities}))
```

However I can't get it to iterate over each row to populate the TRAIN_DATA. Sometimes there are multiple entities within the annotation column.

Grateful if anyone can highlight where I'm going wrong and how to correct it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip()` function:

```py
TRAIN_DATA = [
    (t, {"entities": [(s, e, l) for (l, s, e) in a]})
    for t, a in zip(df["text"], df["annotation"])
]
print(TRAIN_DATA)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    ("some text", {"entities": [(23, 47, "Consequence")]}),
    (
        "some other text",
        {"entities": [(33, 46, "Consequence"), (101, 150, "Cause")]},
    ),
]
```

Comment: Thanks! thats more elegant than what I was trying. Unfortunately I get a value error: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)` which is what I got on some of the other methods I tried, not sure how to correct this as the values should match...

Comment: @Jon make sure you have tuples of lenght 3 in the `annotation` column. You can preprocess the data before and remove/change invalid tuples.